# Not able to deploy portlet from command prompt

Tags: liferay

We are using JDK 7 for Liferay portlet development.
The eclipse as well as the system is configured to use JDK 7.

But when I deploy my portlet from eclipse it works but if I try using ant clean deploy from command prompt it says Java version 7 or higher is needed.

Anyone knows how to fix it so that I can deploy it from command prompt as well.

Note : Java –version from command prompt shows java version as 1.7. Ant version 1.9.4. Liferay version 6.2 EE

Regards,

Tina

Comment: sigh, some basic etiquette: When you're asking on many different platforms, please crossreference your posts: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47775740. Others might find this question, but not the answers there. Or people invest time here, not knowing that the answer is already provided somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided at - https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/47778061

Changing the build.properties file with the java version as 1.7 fixed the problem.

Tina